# Is there a better more efficient way to write the code below for extracting text that starts with '#'

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

```
import numpy as np
hash_list = [['obi', 'is', '#alive'],['oge', 'is', 'beautiful'],
                ['Ade', 'the', '#comedian', 'de', '#rich'],['Jesus', 'wept']]
print(hash_list)
```

**Output:** `[['obi', 'is', '#alive'], ['oge', 'is', 'beautiful'], ['Ade', 'the', '#comedian', 'de', '#rich'], ['Jesus', 'wept']]`

Below is the code I need to optimize for performance. It takes too long(like exponentially) to run the code as the list increases in size

```
a=[]
for x in hash_list:
    b=[]
    a.append(b)  
    for i in x:      
        if i[0]=="#":
            b.append(i)
    
for x in range(len(a)):
    if a[x]==[]:
        a[x]=np.nan
print(a)
```

**Output:** `[['#alive'], nan, ['#comedian', '#rich'], nan]`

Comment: This code is *not* exponential.

Comment: The work being done in the bottom loop (replacing empty lists w/ `nan`s) could be done in the top one.